# Unauthenticated api laravel subdomain

Tags: jquery, laravel, api, cors

I am having ajax api laravel problem Unauthenticated. Please help me

Api: http://localhost/api/v1/verify/telephone/send_code -> error

Api: http://seller.localhost/api/v1verify/telephone/send_code  -> OK

Webview: http://seller.localhost

> This is error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost/api/v1/verify/telephone/send_code' from origin
> 'http://seller.localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which
> must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
> credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
> controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

**Here my code in seller.localhost:**

```
         $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': crsf_token,
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                },
          });
            
              $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/api/v1/verify/telephone/send_code',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {telephone: $('input[name="telephone"]').val()},
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function () {
                }
             });
```

**This is cors set header**

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token');

    }
}
```

**Middlware cors in kernel**

```
    protected $middleware = [
        ....
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
    ];
  protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

API ROUTE

```
 protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

Comment: I've recently had similar issues and found switching from Ajax to Fetch solves this problem (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Have you also tried setting the CORS header values in htaccess?

Comment: No, I set cors value in php header.

Comment: I would switch the Ajax to a fetch function as that should solve it. I will add an answer with an example

Comment: Are you using this `fruitcake/laravel-cors` package?

Comment: No Im using class Cors  middware   return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token');

Answer (score 0):

If you switched to a fetch function you can just call getJSON() function instead of your $.ajax call

```
async function getJSON() {
    // Get data to send
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('telephone', $('input[name="telephone"]').val());

    // Set the fetch options
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }

    // Get the data
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/api/v1/verify/telephone/send_code', options)
        .catch(error => {
            alert('Issue: ' + error);
        });

    // Get the JSON response
    const json = await response.json();

    console.log(json);
}
```

If your CORS declaration works then this should work.

Comment: I try it but not attack cookie for verify auth

Comment: Response {message: "Unauthenticated."}
message: "Unauthenticated."